# PHP inserting data fail

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a table called picture(id, pic, date_posted). I want to insert the picture's url into the `'Pics'` directory in my website from my index.php page. I used the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    //sever is already connected, and database has already been selected
    $name = str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES['img']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], 'Pics/'.$name);

    //my sql statement that I think it doesn't work

    $sql = "INSERT INTO picture(pic, date_posted) VALUES(Pics/'".$name. "', ".time().")";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $on) or die(mysql_error());

    //displaying the result
    $sql_dislay = "SELECT * FROM picture";
    $result_display = mysql_query($sql_display, $con) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<table border=1>
            <tr>
               <th>ID</th>
               <th>Image</th>
               <th>Date Uploaded</th>
            </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_display)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $pic = $row['pic'];
        $d = $row['date_posted'];

        echo "<tr>
                 <td>$id</td>
                 <td>$pic</td>
                 <td>$d</td>
              </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

I got the error message from the sql statement 'Unknown column 'Pics' in 'field list'. But actually I want to insert the url of the image to the table, let say 'Pics/image001.jpg' then when I retrieved the result, it'll be what I want. Once again, the date posted is 0000-00-00 which is not the result I wanted.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO picture(pic, date_posted) VALUES('Pics/".$name. "', ".time().")";
```

The quotes in the values should start before `Pics`.

And regarding the date, The best thing to do would be to use the [ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html), if the `date_posted` field is of the type `timestamp`. About your problem, `time()`

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

So, if you want to use `time()`, then you can use [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to convert into time stamp

Comment: thanks guy, it works. But the date_posted column display 0000-00-00 what should I do?

Comment: Balanicash is exactly right. The reason you want to do this is that the entire value `Pics/your_file_name.jpg` is a string, not just the name of the file.

Comment: For the time, use the MySQL `NOW()` function instead of PHP's `time`. That way, you don't have to deal with formatting the date. 

`$sql = "INSERT INTO picture(pic, date_posted) VALUES('Pics/".$name. "', NOW())";`